# Azure Logic App timeout after 1 minute with SAP and Hybrid Connector

Tags: azure, timeout, hybrid, sap-dotnet-connector, azure-logic-apps

Currently I am trying to connect a Azure Logic App to our OnPrem-SAP System so we can call RFC within Azure.

Therefore I created an Azure SAP Connector and opened the required Firewall Ports (which was tricky enough but the connection Azure <--> OnPrem-SAP is working now). Also our Azure SAP Connector is already able to call an RFC located in our OnPrem-SAP System (SAP Log-Entry available).

**But**: the SAP Connector never gets any response from the Hybrid Connection as the Logic App always returns a Timeout after 1 Minute:

[image]

The LogicApp only contains the SAP Connector which calls a long-running RFC and is started manually.

Within the SAP-Log we can find the following message: "Connection reset by peer."

Now my actual question: 
Is there any possibility to increase the timeout value within azure? Or do I need to *tune* our SAP RFC to run within 1 minute as this is the fixed max-timeout-value by Azure?

Thanks in advance for any advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out those 60 seconds were kind of hardcoded within the SAP Connector from Microsoft we decided to change our RFC to accept an additional paramaters. Instead of `"give me all Data"` we split that opertion into: `"Give me all Data from department A"` and subsequent `"Give me all Data from department B"`.

As this change helped us to create RFC-Calls which do not run longer than 40 seconds we do not face this timeout-issue anymore. Everything is now working as expected.

Maybe it would be a good idea to document this 60-seconds-issue somewhere. Or even better: maybe one day you can adjust this setting as an additional parameter within the LogicApp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SAP Connector from Microsoft, which you can install from the Azure Marketplace gallery?  Our, are you writing your own? [Because it is not clear to me when you said you are creating one]

Currently, we don't provide the timeout as something that an end user will come and tweak.  There is a proper async pattern that logic app and the API apps (connectors) should follow for long running operation.

The SAP Connector, in this case, expected the RFC call to come back in a reasonable time. Which is not the case here and hence the timeout. To be honest, we expected all RFC calls to complete well within a minute.  So, how long does your RFC call take?  It would be good to know this, because there are timeouts everywhere, and there are many moving parts in a hybrid scenario (logic app, API app, SB relays, on premise agent, sap connector, etc).

Thanks
Sameer

Comment: I use the offical SAP Connector from Microsoft which is available in the Marketplace. Our RFC-Call takes about 60 to 70 seconds when it is called directly within the SAP system. Adding a few delay caused by Network (connecting from Azure to OnPremise) we were always 60+ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my part, I observed that the 60sec limit is imposed on all of the API App that is used in Logic App. I have been experiencing this with my API App, once it reaches over 60sec the timeout will occur. You can find the same issue with suggested work-around in this link [API App times out after 1 minute in Logic Apps](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ec71659-20c0-405f-9ebe-ab1b8af2bc2d/api-app-times-out-after-1-minute-in-logic-apps)